# How to operate with PublishSubject as with Observable

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a PublishSubject:

```
PublishSubject<MyEvent> subject = PublishSubject.create();
```

And I need to get internal Observable and perform some actions on it. 
Simple case for now(the code is broken because doOnNext return `Observable` and I need `Subject`):

```
PublishSubject.create().doOnNext(new Action1<MyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void call(MyEvent o) {
            System.out.println("my event:"+o);
        }
    }));
```

I see two ways to do this.
First is - create own subscriber and create PublishSubject based on it.
Second - merge internal subscriber with own.

But I don't know how to implement any of these methods.

Comment: It is not clear what you want (internal subscriber?). Can you add more detail.

Comment: I want to create subject that will fire events from `onNext` and also will fire events from another(parent) observer

Comment: Just call `doOnNext(x -> subject.onNext(x))` from the other observable? You may need to show us the other observable for us to show you your options in knitting them together.